# Pandas - Groupby or Cut multi dataframes to bins

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, data-visualization

I'm having a dataframe with starting axis points and their end points like this

```
x       y       x_end   y_end   distance
14.14   30.450  31.71   41.265  20.631750
-27.02  55.650  -33.60  63.000  9.865034
-19.25  70.665  -28.98  80.115  13.563753
16.45   59.115  9.94    41.895  18.409468
```

I'm drawing a heatmap. I need each "zone" of that map has a line which shows the average distance and angle of lines which have x/y from that zone and their x_end/y_end. It looks like this
[image]

My bins is

```
xbins = np.linspace(-35, 35, 11)

ybins = np.linspace(0, 105, 22)
```

I've already plotted a heatmap

[image]

I'm looking for something like this

```
Bins_X           Bins_Y     Average_X_End   Average_Y_End   Average_Distance
(-35.0, -28.0]  (0, 5.0]    31.71           41.265          20.631750
(-28.0, -21.0]  (0, 5.0]    -33.60          63.000          9.865034
(-21.0, -14.0]  (0, 5.0]    -28.98          80.115          13.563753
(-14.0, -7.0]   (0, 5.0]    9.94            41.895          18.409468
(-35.0, -28.0]  (5.0, 10.0] 41.265          31.71           13.563753
(-28.0, -21.0]  (5.0, 10.0] 63.000          -33.60          18.409468
(-21.0, -14.0]  (5.0, 10.0] 80.115          -28.98          20.631750
(-14.0, -7.0]   (5.0, 10.0] 41.895          9.94            9.865034
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
(df.drop(['x','y'], axis=1)
  .groupby([pd.cut(df.x, xbins),
            pd.cut(df.y, ybins)],
          )
   .mean()
   .dropna(how='all')
   .add_prefix('Average_')
)
```

Output:

```
                             Average_x_end  Average_y_end  Average_distance
x              y                                                           
(-28.0, -21.0] (55.0, 60.0]         -33.60         63.000          9.865034
(-21.0, -14.0] (70.0, 75.0]         -28.98         80.115         13.563753
(14.0, 21.0]   (30.0, 35.0]          31.71         41.265         20.631750
               (55.0, 60.0]           9.94         41.895         18.409468
```

Comment: I'm a newbie, so can you explain how it calculated average of x_end and y_end without mention any 'x_end', 'y_end' ?

Comment: It calculates the average off all columns in `df`, except for `x,y` which were dropped before grouping.

Comment: another noob question: the result seems not to be a dataframe. How can I get the x and y to draw a line from (x, y) to (x_end, y_end) ? (Seems the distance is quite redundant here)

Comment: ah it's a dataframe. But can't call df['x'], only df['Average_x_end'].

Comment: After groupby `x` is an index. You can chain `reset_index()` to the above and get a column named `x` again.

Comment: anyway, maybe I'll find out how to get the mean of bins. You answered my question. Cảm ơn anh nhiều ạ :D

Comment: What do you mean by *mean of bins*?

Comment: I actually only need to find the mean of each "zone", like the mean of (-28.0, -21.0], so I can plot line from the center of the zone

Comment: Isn't it just `(-28 - 21)/2`? Or do you want the average of the `x` within that range? If so, you don't need to drop `x,y` with `.drop`.

Comment: yeah, but I try to get that from the dataframe, not from typing all the mean calculating and comparison

Comment: yeah I already removed the 'drop', but I want to plot from the center of the "zone" which is ((-28 - 21)/2, (55.0 + 60.0)/2). I want to get that mean from the dataframe.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208860/discussion-between-chris-maverick-and-quang-hoang).